# How to find guid of linux distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, guid

I was following this [tutorial on how to setup wsl and zsh](https://yduman.github.io/blog/wsl2-setup/).

I am at this step:

> I wanted WSL2 to be my main profile. You can achieve this by copying the guid value of your Linux distribution into defaultProfile

Of course, the tutorial doesn't say how you get a hold on the guid value of your linux distro.

My linux distro is `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`, how do I find its guid?

Comment: The instructions are simply referring to the PowerShell command  **[guid]::NewGuid()**, this simply generates a unique global id

Answer (score 0):

I found it by opening "windows terminal" then pressing `ctrl+,` which prompted me with `settings.json` in it there was a list of the guid of different terminals.
Amongst these I found the guid for ubuntu 20.04 LTS.